# Greasemonkey script Auto click javascript button (ajax?)

Tags: greasemonkey

Ok Here is the source of the page.

```
<div id="socialBox"></div>
<div class="friendButton addFriend">
    <a>+friend</a>
</div>
```

Here is my greasemonkey code

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Auto click
// @namespace   Auto click
// @description Auto click
// @include     https://*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant       GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==

waitForKeyElements ("#friendButton addFriend", triggerMostButtons);

function triggerMostButtons (jNode) {
    triggerMouseEvent (jNode[0], "mouseover");
    triggerMouseEvent (jNode[0], "mousedown");
    triggerMouseEvent (jNode[0], "click");
    triggerMouseEvent (jNode[0], "mouseup");
}


function triggerMouseEvent  (node, eventType) {
    var clickEvent  = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');
    clickEvent.initEvent (eventType, true, true);
    node.dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
}
```

greasemonkey says its executing the code so it clearly doesn't work. Let me know if you need more info

Comment: The problem is that you used `"#friendButton addFriend"` when it needs to be `".friendButton.addFriend a"` for the HTML you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder if the code below is what you want.

```
document.querySelector('.friendButton.addFriend a').click()
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Yfa6f/1/)

You'd better provide a link to one of the pages on which you want your script executed, so that I can make sure the script will work as expected.

Comment: Do you have an email I can message you at? or is there a way to message on here? for the webpage address, the above didnt work either

Comment: The code you posted worked for a button right beside the button i wanted to press but not this one.. Don't know if you need to know this but the button im trying to press just sends a post request (add, id, token) and changes the text on the button if successful

Comment: @user3471068 You have to post more HTML source code in order to clarify what you are referring to. From the current source code I can only see one element that might contain a button.

Comment: Your answer you gave me was correct. It wont let me upvote it and I swear I answered this question. But yes, the button was in ajax so the script was running before the button loaded. So i just set a timeout and your code worked :)

Comment: Would you mind taking a look at:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22712942/greasemonkey-wait-for-ajax

You seem to know your stuff :)