# Greasemonkey wait for ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, greasemonkey

I have this code I want to execute it should open any links with the phrase "/ThisWord/" in it

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Test
// @namespace   Test
// @description Test  
// @version     1
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js
// @grant       none
// @include     http://website.com/
// ==/UserScript==

setTimeout(testLinks, 10000);

function testLinks() {
var UseThisone = $("a:contains('/profile/')");
GM_openInTab(UseThisone[0].href);

}
```

I just wrappedd the whole thing with a timeout, but i cant get any links to open

Does the above code even work? I can't seem to get it to open the urls let alone in a new tab

One more thing, I would want it to open each Url in 10 second intervals, is that possible?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What ajax are you talking about? In the GM script or the new window? There is no way to know if the ajax is done loading outside of the ajax request itself because an ajax request can be made at any time after the page loads, since they are asynchronous. Do you want to know when any ajax calls that were initiated during the page load are complete?

Comment: If what you are suggesting would help then yes. I know the ajax loads as soon as the page fully loads though. That being the problem since the script will run before that. Is there a way I could just set a timer so the script runs after like 1 minute to give the ajax time to load? would that be easiest? and if i do that how would i make it so it loads a link every 10 secs after that minute?

Comment: I think you just need a delegate so that whenever new elements are added that match the selector the code is applied. Maybe bind the selector to the load event.

Answer (score 1):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Test
// @namespace   Test
// @description Test  
// @version     1
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js
// @grant       GM_openInTab
// @include     http://website.com/
// ==/UserScript==
setTimeout(testLinks, 10000);
function testLinks() {
    var INTERVAL = 10000;
    var delay = -INTERVAL;
    $('a[href*="/profile/"]').each(function(i, el) {
        //avoid infinite recursion, which is subject to @include rules
        if(el.href != location.href) {
            var d = (delay += INTERVAL);
            setTimeout(function() {
                GM_openInTab(el.href);
            }, d);
        }
    });
}
```